# Add flake8 ignore comment automatically from syntastic location list

Tags: plugin-syntastic, location-list

I'm using synatastic with flake8 in neovim for python development. I want to name variables in upper case occasionally but I don't want to turn the warning off completely. However I get bored of adding the comments to the end of lines to silence the flake8 warnings/errors (like the following one):

```python
R = E_pi_sqroot.T @ A @ E_pi_sqroot  # noqa: N806
```

In general I would like to silence any flake8 warning in the location list with a mapping so it would not always be `N806` but should be acquired from the location window line:

```
experimental/one_shot/rkda.py|108 col 26 warning| argument name 'X' should be lowercase [N803]
experimental/one_shot/rkda.py|119 col 10 warning| variable 'K' in function should be lowercase [N806]
```

Is there an easy way to create a mapping that would just add the correct `noqa` end of line comment if I am on the line in the code buffer or location window? I don't know where to start with this one.

Comment: So, is it always N806, or could it be different numbers? Please [edit] to clarify. (And if it could be other numbers, can we see some examples of where those come from?)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thx for the comment. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one answer would be a mapping to (untested)

```
$yi[<CR>A # noqa: <esc>p
```

(I think `$yi[<CR>put =' # noqa: '.@@<CR>J` is equivalent.)

You would want to map this in the quickfix (loclist) buffer (using `nnoremap <buffer>`, probably in an ftplugin or autocommand), but I'm not sure how to do so only for the *right* quickfix (loclist) buffer.

Another option would be to have the mapping in python files, and then prepend `:lopen<CR>` or `:copen<CR>` to the mapping, depending on where you have the results.

Comment: Thx @d-ben-knoble! I'll give it a try.

Comment: That pretty much worked out of the box. I ended up with: ```nnoremap <LocalLeader>f8i $yi[<CR>A  # noqa: <esc>p```

Comment: Just a quick note for the version to be called from the python file it should be `:lopen` not `:copen`, for example: `nnoremap <LocalLeader>f8i :lopen<CR>$yi[<CR>A  # noqa: <esc>p`